# Adding a mocked UIView to a view hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ocmock

I'm trying to write unit tests in which I pass a mocked UIView that is added to the view hierarchy. Here's a basic reproduction:

```
- (void)testUIView {
    UIView *realView = [UIView new];
    UIView *mockView = OCMClassMock(realView);
    UIView *theSuperView = [UIView new];
    [theSuperView addSubview:mockView]
}
```

And the error is:

```
[__NSArrayM superlayer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe0ca43fa00
```

Any idea how I can work around that? The view needs to be mocked because I want to ensure some methods are called on the UIView.

Comment: Why are you attempting to mock a UIView?

Comment: It's actually a WKWebView, I'm mocking it because I'd like to avoid networking/rendering